# Reusing a variable from a for loop, out of the for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
    for x in range(len(Bodies):
        planet = Bodies[x]
        if planet == planetinit:
            expression

        else:

            fx = -gravconst*rx/r3
            templistx.append(fx)
            forcex = sum(templistx)
            templistx.clear()
    vx += (forcex/Bodies[n].M)*dt
```

I want to use the forcex, outside of the loop, but this is not possible and I get the error:
NameError: name 'forcex' is not defined

Comment: If they exist in the loop, they should also exist after it.

Comment: You are probably getting that error inside the `for` loop, since the loop and the block underneath should share the same scope. Show a [MCVE] of your code and give us the full traceback.

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis in `range(len(Bodies)`, that probably also causes problems. You should simply replace `for x in range(len(Bodies)): planet = Bodies[x]` by `for planet in Bodies:`.

Comment: In your updated code, if no planet is different from `planetinit`, the `else` part is not executed, and `forcex` will not be defined after the loop.

Comment: I deleted some code so that it would be more compact, so the else does execute, but when I try to use it in the vx += expression, it gives me that error

Answer (score 3):

You should define the lists before the loop as empty lists.

```
templistx = []
templisty = []
templistz = []
for x in range(len(Bodies)):
    planet = Bodies[x]
    if planet == planetinit:
        leftover_bin.append(0)
        .
        .
        .
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed the variables, could you take a look at it, as it is now, because this is how I coded it until now

Comment: @IanRonk, try defining forcex before the loop. i.e: `forcex = None`